# WISiWYG with uploading pictures: Django way

Tags: django, file-upload, django-admin

I'm trying to integrate TinyMCE or CKEditor into Django, but I have no idea how to manage uploading pictures.
I've been searching and found some django apps, but they won't work with my Django version (1.1.1), buggy and not maintained.

Maybe I missed something? Can you please give me a step-by-step guide how to add WYSIWYG with uploading into django form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use TinyMCE or CKEditor with [django-filebrowser](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser).

Description from the official site:

> The FileBrowser is an extension to the Django Admin-Interface in order to
>
> - browse directories on your server and upload/delete/edit/rename files.
> - include images/documents to your models/database using the FileBrowseField.
> - select images/documents for TinyMCE and CKEditor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django-tinymce-filebrowser

Its allow to manage images and files from tinyMCE

Comment: This library seems to have fallen behind current versions of TinyMCE, and it seems as though they are not compatible at the moment.